# t-SNE plot with labels

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I have a data frame with more than 5000 lines.

A small example with few lines:

```
df <- structure(list(i_name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 
9L, 10L, 8L), .Label = c("An19", "An31", "An37", "An38", "An54", 
"An56", "An59", "An6", "An65", "An9"), class = "factor"), t_factor = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L), out = c(2.72662448798073, 
0.857435104262549, 1.33378064244986, 1.67672325941268, 1.81053565604612, 
2.35244174245512, 1.46331663415767, 2.79710579828126, 0.715497242875863, 
1.80209614111343)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Looks like this:

```
┌────┬────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│    │ i_name │ t_factor │    out    │
├────┼────────┼──────────┼───────────┤
│  1 │ An5    │        0 │ 2.7266245 │
│  2 │ An6    │        1 │ 0.8574351 │
│  3 │ An5    │        1 │ 1.3337806 │
│  4 │ An59   │        2 │ 1.6767233 │
│  5 │ An5    │        2 │ 1.8105357 │
│  6 │ An7    │        1 │ 2.3524417 │
│  7 │ An6    │        2 │ 1.4633166 │
│  8 │ An7    │        0 │ 2.7971058 │
│  9 │ An7    │        2 │ 0.7154972 │
│ 10 │ An6    │        0 │ 1.8020961 │
└────┴────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

More lines can be produced using:

```
df <- data.frame("i_name" = paste("An", sample(1:65, 2000, replace=T) , sep = ""), "t_factor" = sample(0:2, 2000, replace=T), "out" = runif(2000, 0.01, 2.9))
```

I would like to reduce the dimensions and check if a pattern exists using t-SNE (t-distributed stochastic neighbor embedding) or k-means and put labels like this image:

[image: t-SNE on data]

So far I've done this:

```
tsne_model_1 = Rtsne(as.matrix(df[,2:3]), check_duplicates=FALSE, pca=TRUE, perplexity=5, theta=0.5, dims=3)
d_tsne_1 = as.data.frame(tsne_model_1$Y)
# k-means and hierarchical cluster models
d_tsne_1_original=d_tsne_1
fit_cluster_kmeans=kmeans(scale(d_tsne_1), 3)
d_tsne_1_original$cl_kmeans = factor(fit_cluster_kmeans$cluster)
fit_cluster_hierarchical=hclust(dist(scale(d_tsne_1)))
## 3 clusters
d_tsne_1_original$cl_hierarchical = factor(cutree(fit_cluster_hierarchical, k=3))
plot_cluster=function(data, var_cluster, palette){
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x="V1", y="V2", color=var_cluster)) +
    geom_point(size=1.25) +
    guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=6))) +
    xlab("") + ylab("") +
    ggtitle("") +
    theme_light(base_size=20) +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          legend.direction = "horizontal", 
          legend.position = "bottom",
          legend.box = "horizontal") + 
    scale_colour_brewer(palette = palette) 
}
plot_k=plot_cluster(d_tsne_1_original, "cl_kmeans", "Accent")
plot_h=plot_cluster(d_tsne_1_original, "cl_hierarchical", "Set1")
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot_k, plot_h,  ncol=2)
```

Producing this:

[image: Plot without labels]

Comment: On such data, tSNE can produce *artifacts* that look like patterns even in uniform random data.